# Forcing timeout in C# app on call to sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am testing out a c# app that invokes a stored proc in sql server 2014.  Specifically I want to test how the app reacts to a timeout encountered running the sp.

I've setup a lock in management studio using waifor which works like a champ.  Where I'm stuck is I've changed all the configuration parameters I can find in my sql server but the sp still waits for the waitfor code to run then happily processes the update.

Is there a way to configure how long the call to the db will wait for a return before timing out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456330/how-to-organize-infinite-while-loop-in-sql-server might assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server never times out queries. The client does that. Configure the `CommandTimeout` property in ADO.NET.